# Where can I find statistics on package downloads and dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, deb

Is there a site that lists (or ranks) Ubuntu/Debian packages by downloads or dependency count? The Node.js package manager [npm has leaderboards](https://www.npmjs.org/), [as does PyPI (unofficially)](http://pypi-ranking.info/alltime). It'd be interesting to see which packages are used and downloaded most often.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debian has the popularity contest: http://popcon.debian.org/

Comment: I don't know how broad the userbase is , but note that the participation in the popcon needs to be explicitly enabled by the user.

Comment: Hopefully the sample is representative - if you know of any other sources (partial or comprehensive), feel free to include them.

Comment: This is the accepted answer.Does that mean, that Ubuntu is not recording download counts for packages?

Comment: @DarkTrick no we have a dedicated website for generic stats (like type of install, type of graphics card) Not sure how recent One sec gonna find it now

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/desktop/statistics this is it

Answer (score 0):

You can also use hw-probe and query https://linux-hardware.org/?view=trends&period=0

Select: All time, Debian

Ok that's much smaller participants...

Comment: How to select to see app usage statistics- how many times each app has been installed?

Comment: That you find at https://popcon.debian.org/